# How to get only one instance when calling GetCallbackChannel()?

Tags: c#, wcf, callback, instance

I'm having a little problem with my WCF service.
Actually, a user can subscribe to a "publishing" service.

I'm simply doing a `OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IPublishing>();`
Then I add the the returned object into a List (a kind of `List<IPublishing>`)

As I want my clients to be notified when I publish a message, I simply call the callback of all the subscribed users.

It works great, but a user can subscribe twice and I don't want to.
It's why I do a `if (!theList.Contains(theCallbackChannelReturned))` in order to verify this constraint...

The fact here is that everytime I create the callbackchannel, it seems that he create another new instance of IPublishing, even on the same client...

I don't know how to do to accomplish this... I figured out that `OperationContext.Current.InstanceContext` returns still the same Hashcode but
GetCallbackChannel doesn't...

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

In your client callback implementation you should do the following:

```
[CallbackBehavior(
    ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant, 
    UseSynchronizationContext = false)]
public partial class ServiceClient : IMyService_Callback 
{ .... }
```